# Appcelerator Arrow App - limitation on publishing max 10 versions?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

When trying to publish a new version of the Appcelerator Arrow application, I get the following error

```
ERROR  | App {MyArrowApp} has been published 10 (maximum) versions.
```

There is no documentation on Appcelerator about such a restriction anywhere, so I'm stumped! That said, how do I delete the old versions to get around this problem - I don't care for prior versions to be maintained except for the active one?

Please note that I have a paid subscription to the Appcelerator Arrow platform, so this is even more surprising.

Answer (score 0):

As per Appcelerator Support (refreshingly helpful):

Please read the following sections:

```
--delete_oldest
--list_versions
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Arrow_Cloud_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-43299782_ArrowCloudCommand-LineInterfaceReference-publish